# CMAC operation on HSM

Tags: encryption, aes, cmac

I have generated an AES key on HSM and I need to calculate the CMAC between this key with an input value. Is it possible to do this on HSM? What is the mechanism to invoke?

Comment: Could you elaborate on the brand and model and version of the HSM?

Comment: Also, most likely this should be a question for your HSM vendor's support contact and _potentially_ [so] if you have concrete questions on the code. Though there is some leeway for this question to be answered here, depending on the precise direction, e.g. whether it asks for how to actually do that, whether it is supported by PKCS#11 / <Other HSM Interface Standard> / ...

Comment: https://www.cryptsoft.com/pkcs11doc/v230/group__SEC__11__12__AES__CMAC.html That took about a second to type into Google. I don't know if your HSM supports it of course, for that you have to answer kelalaka's question.